# AJAX Not Running On Dialog Box Button Click

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Firstly, apologies because I've only just started to use Javascript, so I'm perhaps I'm making a very basic mistake, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to implement `Example 2` from [this](http://s3.envato.com/files/293712/index.html) piece of third party software in my gallery page shown [here](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/testgallery#/0).

Shown in the code below, I've been able to add the message to the onclick event i.e. when the user clicks the 'bin' icon, but the AJAX piece of code that is supposed to run upon the 'Delete' button being clicked is failing:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    Galleria.ready(function() {
        this.$('thumblink').click();

    $(".galleria-image").append( 
    "<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
    $(".btn-delete").live("click", function(){
    $.msgbox("You are about to delete this image. It cannot be restored at a later date. Do you wish to continue?", {
    type: "alert",
      buttons : [
        {type: "submit", value: "Delete"},
        {type: "cancel", value: "Cancel"}
      ]
      },function(Delete) {
      var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); 
      // send the AJAX request
      $.ajax({
        url : 'delete.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : { image : img.attr('src'),  userid: "VALUE", locationid: "VALUE"},
        success : function(){
        img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
    }
    });               
    });
    return false;
    });     
    });

</script>
```

I'm really not sure where I've gone wrong here, despite spending some time disecting the code. I just wondered whether someone could perhaps look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

**POST UPDATE
WORKING SOLUTION**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

        Galleria.ready(function() {
            this.$('thumblink').click();

        $(".galleria-image").append( 
        "<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
        $(".btn-delete").live("click", function(){  
        var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); 
        $.msgbox("You are about to delete this image. It cannot be restored at a later date. Do you wish to continue?", {
        type: "alert",
          buttons : [
            {type: "submit", value: "Delete"},
            {type: "cancel", value: "Cancel"}
          ]
          },
          function(result) {
          if(result)

          // send the AJAX request
          $.ajax({
            url : 'delete.php',
            type : 'post',
            data : { image : img.attr('src'),  userid: "VALUE", locationid: "VALUE"},
            success : function(){
            img.parent().fadeOut('slow');

    }
        });               
        });
        return false;
        });     
        });

    </script>
```

Many thanks and regards

Comment: does it throw any error? can you please check javascript console and see if there are any JS errors?

Comment: Hi @Asdfg, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I've just gone into Firefox and run the page. Unfortunately, it dopesnt display any error messages. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM install firebug addon, turn it on after the browser restarts by pressing F12, turn on the console, refresh the page, submit your request in the html page and look for errors in the console

Comment: can you put the alert message in the delete function and see if that gets called? Also can you define the failure ajax block and see if there is an error in the AJAX call? Also i suspect your JSON format for passing the data is not correct.

Comment: @Asdfg, thank you for your continued help with this. I personally think that is the answer, certianly in light of my findings from Matej Konecy suggestion, but I don't know how to do this. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have renamed the variable `Delete` to `result`.

```
function(result) {
  //result variable holds the value of what user clicks 'Delete' or 'Cancel'. 
  //Cancel click will pass false.
  //Delete click will pass Delete.
  alert(result)
  //You can also check if(result=='Delete') instead of if(result)
  if(result)
  {
      var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); 
      // send the AJAX request
      $.ajax({
        url : 'delete.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : { image : img.attr('src'),  userid: "VALUE", locationid: "VALUE"},
        success : function(){
        img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
    }
  }
```

See if this works.

Comment: Hi @Asdfg, thank you very much for this. I'm sure I've implemented this correctly, but unfortunately the 'thumnail' view is no longer functioning. I've updated the link that I used in my initial post to illustrate this, perhaps a lot better than I can explain. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi @Asdfg, thank you for your time, trouble and help with this. I've done some more work on this and I've now managed to get this to work. It was a very minor amendment to your code, but I've added it to my original post for reference. Once again, many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `this` in the msgbox callback isn't an element (in other words, the `img` variable is an empty array. Try to put the `var img` declaration right into the onclick listener.

```
$(".btn-delete").live("click", function(){
var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img");
```

Did it help?

Comment: Hi @Matej Konecny, thank you for repsonding to my post and for the suggestion. This does work, but unfortunately it deletes the image when the 'cancel is selected. Kind regards

Comment: You need to check the 'Delete' variables value before executing the AJAX call.

Comment: Hi @Asdfg thank you for this. I'm afraid this is where my lack of Javascript knowledge is letting me down. My apologies, but could you perhaps elaborate about how I go about this please? Kind regards